# New theme integration on multi site website in magento not showing changes on frontend

Tags: magento, themes, multisite

I have created a new theme from scratch for my multi site website. I have uploaded the theme folders, skin folders and made changes in admin>configuration>web and in design for store scope. Also i have cleared all the cache. After all these changes i cannot able to see changes on my new website(website 2) it is loading the current theme of the website 1. Please suggest the best answer for this.

Comment: is your theme showing under Catalog > manage products > Design section?

Comment: Please check in which package under you upload your theme as well as checked it in admin as well.